# NVL function in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, select, nvl

I do not have data in one of the tables in the following query; my result set is empty. I'm trying to use NVL() FUNCTION, however; it still gives empty set.
Can someone help me to understand this behaviour. My expectation was to display '0', however; getting empty result. I'm using oracle 11g.

```
SELECT NVL(T8.COLLECTION_BALANCE_AMT, 0)
      from BV_COLLECTION_CLAIM T8 JOIN BV_CLAIM_LIABLE_INDV T2
      ON T8.CLAIM_ID = T2.CLAIM_ID
      JOIN BV_CLAIM_RECOVERY T3
      ON T8.CLAIM_ID = T3.CLAIM_ID
```

Comment: Well, is there actually a row coming back?  NVL is for null values in a row, not for non-existent rows.

Comment: Now row if I understood the op correct.

Comment: Well, apparently you have no rows where the JOIN operations succeed, and therefore no row is returned. If you change the `NVL()` to `T8.CLAIM_ID` instead, do you get a row back? If there's no data matching your criteria, you won't get any data.

Comment: `nvl()` is about replacing a `null` value in a *column*, not about adding rows that aren't there

Comment: Thanks everyone, it is now clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `join` only returns matching rows. You're looking for a `left join`, which would return `null` for columns in the joined table where matching **do not exist**:

```
SELECT    NVL(T8.COLLECTION_BALANCE_AMT, 0)
FROM      BV_COLLECTION_CLAIM T8 
LEFT JOIN BV_CLAIM_LIABLE_INDV T2 -- here!
       ON T8.CLAIM_ID = T2.CLAIM_ID
LEFT JOIN BV_CLAIM_RECOVERY T3  -- here too!
       ON T8.CLAIM_ID = T3.CLAIM_ID
```